# Python Parameter Confusion

Tags: python, parameters

I'm a beginner, writing a Python Blackjack script, and got confused about whether or not a function (dealPlayer) needs a parameter. It works either way, with a parameter or without. I'm not sure if I've had a brain fart, or I've not learned something along the way. Here's the code:

```
import random

dealer = []
player = []
c = ""
deck = [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,
            9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11]

def dealPlayer(deck):
    cardOne = random.choice(deck)
    cardTwo = random.choice(deck)
    player.append(cardOne)
    player.append(cardTwo)
    deck.remove(cardOne)
    deck.remove(cardTwo)
```

The question is, do I need (deck) as a parameter in the function? It works with or without (deck) as a parameter. I've gone back over different tutorials, and other's code, but I'm still confused. Thanks for any help.

Comment: did i get you right that if your function is:

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code works with or without `deck` as a parameter is because there is a global variable named `deck`, so when you reference `deck` inside your function, the function will first look for the local variable (the parameter) and then if it doesn't find it, it will look for the global variable.

It's best to refactor your code to not use global variables at all -- define `deck` initially inside a function and then pass that as a result or argument to other functions as needed.  If you don't want to do that, then at least make sure your argument does not shadow (have the same name as) the global variable, to avoid confusion further on.  Or remove the argument entirely and use the global variable only, if that's appropriate for your program.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the help. I'll put it inside a function.

Comment: For future reference, WHY is this bad practice to use Global variables?

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh Quite a few reasons, you can find many here: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad One other reason is that global variable access is much slower in Python compared to local variable access.

Comment: There are a number of reasons, but one important one is that functions should theoretically be portable to other pieces of software.  The arguments of a function are its input and the return value is its output.  If you use global variables, you bypass those and make the operation of the function dependent on its environment.  That means that if you ever want to use your function in another environment -- let's say you want to use the same function for a different card game where there are multiple decks -- it won't work.

Comment: @ChrisKavanagh One other thing, the reason you are able to globally modify the list (when you `append` to it) is because in Python, lists are "mutable." That means they can be "mutated" in-place from anywhere in the program. Many other objects are NOT mutable (strings, tuples, integers, floats), so don't rely too much on that kind of behavior.

Comment: Lol, another small problem. If I put the deck inside a function, I'm not sure hot to use it. How could I use it to deal the cards if it's now inside a function? I understand I could put everything in a Class, and do it that way. But I don't want to do that (at least not now). I may go back and do it that way later, but for now I want to keep it close to the way it is.

Comment: The simple answer is "focus on putting information into your functions as arguments, and then taking the information out of them with `return` values."  But to apply that method skillfully you'll have to change how you think about storing data and performing data manipulation.  For now, consider something like this: instead of picking randomly from the deck, `random.shuffle()` the deck and then use `.pop()` to remove items from the deck individually and assign them to players.  Your function for dealing a card could, for instance, take a deck and a player as arguments.

Comment: In that example scenario, you don't strictly need to `return` anything because you're just modifying the state of existing objects.  Perhaps the ideal function doesn't modify state outside of itself, but that's difficult to apply in this case.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Thank you for your patience Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

did i get you right that if your function is:

```
def dealPlayer():
```

the code still works? this should raise a undefined deck error. EDIT: this was wrong of course its global. And just works without it. but thats a bad practice.

```
def dealPlayer():
    deck = []
```

this should raise a Index Error.

```
cardOne = random.choice()
```

This raises a TypeError.